# Haskell application, or section?

Tags: haskell, operators

I wanted to flip a list constructor usage, to have type:

```
[a] -> a -> [a]
```

(for use in a fold), so tried:

```
(flip :)
```

but it gives the type:

```
Prelude> :t (flip :)
(flip :) :: [(a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c] -> [(a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c]
```

This surprised me, but it appears that this was parsed as a left section of (:), instead of a partial application of flip. Rewriting it using flip as infix seems to overcome this,

```
Prelude> :t ((:) `flip`)
((:) `flip`) :: [a] -> a -> [a]
```

But I couldn't find the rule defining this behavior, and I thought that function application was the highest precedence, and was evaluated left->right, so I would have expected these two forms to be equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was putting `:` in parentheses that made your second example work, not using backticks around `flip`.

We often say that "function application has highest precedence" to emphasise that e.g. `f x + 1` should be read as `(f x) + 1`, and not as `f (x + 1)`. But this isn't really wholly accurate. If it was, and `(flip :)` parsed as you expected, then the highest precedence after `(f x) + 1` would be the application of `(f x)` to `+`; the whole expression `f x + 1` would end up being parsed as `f` applied to 3 arguments: `x`, `+`, and `1`. But this would happen with all expressions involving infix operators! Even a simple `1 + 1` would be recognised as `1` applied to `+` and `1` (and then complain about the missing `Num` instance that would allow `1` to be a function).

Essentially this strict understanding of "function application has highest precedence" would mean that function application would be all that ever happens; infix operators would always end up as arguments to some function, never actually working as infix operators.

Actually precedence (and associativity) are mechanisms for resolving the ambiguity of expressions involving multiple infix operators. Function application is not an infix operator, and simply doesn't take part in the precedence/associativity system. Chains of terms that don't involve operators are resolved as function application *before* precedence is invoked to resolve the operator applications (hence "highest precedence"), but it's not *really* precedence that causes it.

Here's how it works. You start with a linear sequence of terms and operators; there's no structure, they were simply written next to each other.

What I'm calling a "term" here can be a non-operator identifier like `flip`; or a string, character, or numeric literal; or a list expression; or a parenthesised subexpression; etc. They're all opaque as far as this process is concerned; we only know (and only need to know) that they're not infix operators. We can always tell an operator because it will either be a "symbolic" identifier like `++!@>`, or an alphanumeric identifier in backticks.

So, sequence of terms and operators. You find all chains of one or more terms in a row that contain no operators. Each such chain is a chain of function applications, and becomes a single term.<sup>1</sup>

Now if you have two operators directly next to each other you've got an error. If your sequence starts or ends in an operator, that's also an error (unless this is an operator section).

At this point you're guaranteed to have a strictly alternating sequence like term operator term operator term operator term, etc. So you pick the operator with the highest precedence together with the terms to its left and right, call that an operator application, and those three items become a single term. Associativity acts as a tie break when you have multiple operators with the same precedence. Rinse and repeat until the whole expression has become a single term (or associativity fails to break a tie, which is also an error). This means that in an expression involving operators, the "top level application" is *always* one of the operators, never ordinary function application.

A consequence of this is that there are **no circumstances** under which an operator can end up passed as the argument to a function. It's simply impossible. This is why we need the `(:)` syntax to disable the "operator-ness" of operators, and get at their identity as values.

For `flip :` the only chain of non-operator terms is just `flip`, so there's no ordinary function application to resolve "at highest precedence". `:` then goes looking for its left and right arguments (but this is a section, so there's no right argument), and finds `flip`on its left.

To make `flip` receive `:` as an argument instead of the other way around, you must write `flip (:)`. `(:)` is not an operator (it's in parentheses, so it doesn't matter what's inside), and so we have a chain of two terms with no operators, so that gets resolved to a single expression by applying `flip` to `(:)`.

---

<sup>1</sup> The other way to look at this is that you identify all sequences of terms not otherwise separated by operators and insert the "function application operator" between them. This "operator" has higher precedence than it's possible to assign to other operators and is left-associative. Then the operator-resolution logic will automatically treat function application the way I've been describing.

Comment: Thanks - I knew about the parens, just forgot to do it! The explanation of precedence of operator and function application is helpful.

Answer (score 8):

What you want to do is this:

```
λ> :t (flip (:))
(flip (:)) :: [a] -> a -> [a]
```

Operators in Haskell are infix. So when you do `flip :` it operates in an infix fashion i.e. `flip` is applied to `:` function. By putting parenthesis explicitly in `flip (:)`, you tell that `:` should be applied to `flip`. You can also use the backtick operator in `flip` for making that infix which you have tried already.

Comment: Breaking it out helps you see the consistency : `let cons = (:) in flip cons` works, `let cons = : in flip cons` is an error