# Are these two partial applications different? Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to implement the "xor" (exclusive or) function in Haskell in different ways using only partial applications. I am not allowed to use pattern matching or lambda expressions. So my question is, are these two implementations of the xor function any different from each other?

```
xor1 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor1 x = (/=) x

xor2 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor2 x = (/= x)
```

Comment: oh yeah, i made a mistake

Comment: Closely related: [*Haskell application, or section?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27670028/2751851) (I'm not closing against that because, in this question, the main issue is expressed in a clearer way).

Answer (score 5):

> So my question is, are these two implementations of the xor function any different from each other?

Yes! The implementations are different; however, the results will be the same due to the nature of equality.

Let's look at both of these functions, and expand out the point-free piece:

```
xor1 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor1 x y = (/=) x y

xor2 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor2 x y = (/= x) y
```

So if we move these to an infix style to compare, we can more easily see what the difference is in the implementation:

```
xor1 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor1 x y = x /= y 

xor2 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor2 x y = y /= x
```

However, since equality is commutative, these are equivalent expressions.

Since `/=` is defined as an operator, it's behavior is different from normal functions in that it is applied infix by default. This behavior is changed by using the full parenthetical operator `(/=)`. This is the opposite from other functions which have to be expressed as infix using backticks. If we change to using a `notEqual` function that is not an operator, the implementation would be the same!

```
notEqual = (/=)

xor1 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor1 x y = notEqual x y

xor2 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor2 x y = (notEqual x) y = notEqual x y
```

---

As @duplode mentions in the comments, another way to look at this problem is to go fully point-free instead of point-full:

```
xor1 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor1 = (/=) 

xor2 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor2 = flip (/=)
```

Comment: "Let's look at both of these functions, and expand out the point-free piece [...]" -- Or, if we were to make them fully point-free, `xor1 = (/=)`, and `xor2 = flip (/=)`.

Comment: @duplode Exactly right, but I think beginners typically can get confused by point-free notation so I went the opposite direction. Do you mind if I edit that into my answer as an extra example of how to solve this problem?

Comment: Feel free to edit it in. (By the way, I agree with prioritising the pointful way in this answer. To me, the main motivation for also showing the other way would be that `xor1 = (/=)` makes it clear that operators are just functions, with a bit of extra syntactic sugar on the top -- though your `notEqual` example arguably plays that role already.)